# Do I need unity 3D for game card

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I'm a flutter developer, and I want to begin a new card game that we play in my country, but I saw on internet that flutter is not really appropriate for game. So in my research I see unity 3D, I want to know if flutter can be a good solution too, or it will be better for me to made it with unity.

PS : I want my game to be a multiplayer game, like two real person can play one against the other.

Thank for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter is good for building casual games, such as card games and other similar 2D games.

Flutter has some samples and a template to get you started building games here: https://flutter.dev/games also check out more detailed documentation here: https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/games-toolkit

Unity3D is powerful, but very hard to work with. Flutter is easier, but not as powerful and not a good match for 3D games. But for a card game, Flutter is probably a very good match!

For multiplayer you can use Firebase's Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore for example :)

Good luck and have fun! :)